# Keras [Text multi-classification] - Good accuracy in training and test but bad in prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have been facing a several problems when trying to predict topics based on news articles. The news articles have been cleared (no pontuation, numbers, ... ). There are 6 classes possible and I have a dataset of 13000 news articles per each class (Uniform distribution of the data set).

**Pre-processing:**

```
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print ("Index: ", index)
    txt_clean = ' '.join(re.sub("([^a-zA-Z ])", " ", data.loc[index,'txt_clean']).split()).lower()

    word_tokens = word_tokenize(txt_clean) 

    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 
    cleaned_text = ''

    for w in filtered_sentence:
        cleaned_text = cleaned_text + ' ' + w

    data.loc[index,'txt_clean'] = cleaned_text
```

**I implemented a RNN using LSTM as the following:**

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(50000, 100, input_length=500))
    model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(150, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
    model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.1)

    accr = model.evaluate(X_test,Y_test)
    print('Test set\n  Loss: {:0.3f}\n  Accuracy: {:0.3f}'.format(accr[0],accr[1]))
```

**Prediction:**

```
model = load_model('model.h5')
data = data.sample(n=15000)

model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=50000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data['txt_clean'].values) (Prediction data sample values and not the same as in the training))

CATEGORIES = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
for index, row in data.iterrows():


    seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([data.loc[index,'txt_clean']])
    padded = pad_sequences(seq, maxlen=500)

    pred = model.predict(padded)
    pred = pred[0]
    print (pred, pred[np.argmax(pred)]))
```

For example after 10 epochs and a batch_size of 500:

- Training acc: 0.831
- Training loss: 0.513
- Test acc: 0.714
- Test loss: 0.907

Also tried reducing the number of batch_size to 64:

- Training acc: 0.859
- Training loss: 0.415
- Test acc: 0.771
- Test loss: 0.679

The results using 64 batch size seems to me better, BUT when I am predicting news article (one by one) I get an accuracy of 15.97%. This accuracy of prediction is much much low comparing with the training and test.

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: can you add preprocessing steps in your question and how you are taking prediction

Comment: @Mukul I edited the post with the requested information.

Comment: are you using same tokenizer for training a prediction??? - word index may be got changed if you are creating it again for prediction

Comment: If I understand correctly, you train a separate Tokenizer for the prediction data, effectivelly screwing the inputs of the model completely.

Comment: @Mukul and dedObed, Actually I tried both versions. I am first training the module and then in other python file importing the saved model. Thus means I need to create a tokenizer right? When I create the tokenizer I tried to use the same data as in the training and also the prediction data to input it from tokenizer. The prediction is about more 2% with the same tokenizer words but that is not a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical problem that exists in ML or DL. There can be a couple of reasons for it

1. Overfitting, try to make the model deeper or add some normalizations.
2. Train and Test dataset are dissimilar
3. Use the same preprocessing steps as used during training
4. Class imbalance i.e training dataset contains more data for a particular class which test dataset lacks.
5. Try to change model architecture by using Bidirectional LSTM or GRU

Comment: There is the same behavior, couldn't that be a problem in the code? Unfortunately this behavior is not normal because it only appear when I am trying to predict.

Answer (score 0):

Please try pickling your tokenizer using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to save your keras tokenizer use it for both training and prediction.

Here is the sample code to save keras tokenizer :-

```
import pickle

# saving
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# loading
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunatelly I confirmed that I have the same index in both modules but the predictions still very very bad. Any other suggestion @Mukul?

Comment: Use `model.evaluate` on prediction and check whether accuracy you are getting is same or not

Comment: Yes, when I use model.evaluate is the same as the validation accuracy by keras. When I do model.predict the accuracy is much much lower compared with model.evaluate and model.fit (validation accuracy).

Comment: you should raise a bug on Keras Github page,  and try to make this issue reproducible. like providing sample data and models or steps to reproduce it.

Comment: Also, try to switch Keras version. you are using tf.keras or keras ???

Comment: I am using only keras.